# How to remove level 3 heading in toc (markdown)

Tags: python, markdown, tableofcontents

I am trying to create a TOC that uses only 2 levels of headings.

For example in this scenario I want to remove the 2.1.1

```
#1
##1.1
#2
##2.1
###2.1.1
```

the output in TOC should be

```
1
 1.1
2
 2.1
```

Is there any methods to remove the 2.1.1 heading automatically?

Comment: Find a markdown parser, read the document, go through all the headings, remove the headings you don't want to keep, write the rest back to a file. You also may want to read [ask].